# Angular 4 material table doesnt update

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material2

I'm trying to use Angular 4 Material MatTable updating it from my server,
Problem is that it only works once.

I have a search button which activates the Search function, It works once and updates the table, But on the second search it seems just to change the **list length** without updating any of the rows data.

My guess is that I'm just not using BehaviorSubject correctly or I should tell angular to refresh the data somehow Because it does seem the table changes it's length (The scrollbar of the list gets shorter) But it just doesn't refresh the data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
import { ServerApiService } from "../../services/ServerApi.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {Product} from "../../Models/Product";
import {Offer} from "../../Models/Offer";
import {OffersComponent} from "../Offers/Offers.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-store-stats',
    templateUrl: './search-product.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search-product.component.less'],
    providers: [DialogService]
})
/** StoreStats component*/
export class SearchProductComponent implements OnInit {
    keyword: string;
    displayedColumns = ['image', 'position', 'name', 'weight','offers'];
    dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
    dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.dataSubject);
    canSearch = true;

    constructor(private serverApi: ServerApiService, private dialogService: DialogService) {

    }

    showOffers(Offers: Offer[]) {
        this.dialogService.addDialog(OffersComponent, {
            title:'Offers',
            modalOffers: Offers});
    }

    trackByFn(index: number) {
        return index;
    }

    Search() {
        this.canSearch = false;
        this.serverApi.getProducts(this.keyword)
            .subscribe(
                (response) => {
                     let data:Product[] = response.json() as Product[];
                    this.dataSubject.next(data);
                    this.canSearch = true;
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.canSearch = true;
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
    /** Called by Angular after StoreStats component initialized */
    ngOnInit(): void { }
}

/**
 * Data source to provide what data should be rendered in the table. The observable provided
 * in connect should emit exactly the data that should be rendered by the table. If the data is
 * altered, the observable should emit that new set of data on the stream. In our case here,
 * we return a stream that contains only one set of data that doesn't change.
 */

var Offers: Offer[] = new Array<Offer>();
Offers[0] = new Offer("123123", 2,"NEW");
Offers[1] = new Offer("123123", 2,"Like New");

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<Product> {

    constructor(private subject: BehaviorSubject<Product[]>) {
        super ();
    }
    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.subject;
    }
    disconnect() { }
}
```

Comment: To help debug, you can tap into the stream of data going to the table. In `connect()`, do `return this.subject.do(data => console.log('sending to table', data));`

Comment: I know the table gets the data.. for example:
If I first search for football the table gets loaded with football product lets say I found X items
Now the second time I search for basketball
If basketball products count is X+10, Then the table will be loaded with extra 10 items of the basketball search
If it's less or equal you won't see any change...
The table just doesn't update the EXISTING ITEMS but it can add extra items... It doesn't understand the entire collection changed.
It should remove all the football products and add the basketball products, 
is it angular fault or table?@WillHowe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I didn't use the TrackBy function of the table correctly,
Causing it not to understand when an item changes.